# UILabel text doesn't word wrap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a long text string (including `\n` newline characters) that I feed into a `UILabel` for display. The `UILabel` is dynamically set up to provide sufficient space for the text.

My code looks like this:

```
myText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@some text: %@ \n \n %@", myText, moreText1, moreText2];
NSLog(@"%@", myText);
myLabelSize = [vLabelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(15.0)] constrainedToSize:cMaxLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UILabel *lBody = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cFromLeft, vFromTop, vLabelSize.width, vLabelSize.height)];
lBody.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(15.0)];
lBody.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lBody.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;
lBody.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
[myScrollView addSubview:lBody];
lBody.text = vLabelText;
```

My problem is that the text does not wrap, but truncates after the first line. The `\n` newlines are ignored.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Just found the problem, my `numberOfLines` was still at 1. After setting it to 0 it works fine.

Comment: Shoot.. you beat me to it... I had that exact problem and knew when I read your title that I had your solution.

Comment: Man, I hate it when I have to go to the interwebs for something like this. Such an easy thing to forget. +1

Answer (score 1):

May be it will be useful - since some lines are deprecated now

```
lBody.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
lBody.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

and of course - `lBody.numberOfLines` should be more than 1(1 is default value)